# How to load images like grid with price tag on it and name at bottom

Tags: c#

I'm making a Point Of Sale Desktop Application using C#, SQL SERVER. I want to show images of item in grid with price tag and name that is stored in database. When user click on it. It should be add to cart. Can anyone help how to design like that?

I search it on google but couldn't found any useful help.

Comment: Do you want to make a Winforms application or a WPF application?

Comment: This is way too broad. Please read [ask]. You should divide your problem into parts and start searching for pointers on how to do each specific part. Then if you have a specific problem, you can come back and ask about that.

Comment: Did you do any research? Did you try anything on your own to solve this problem?

Comment: The problem is complicate so do one step at a time.  And ask for help on a specific issue.  Do you have images of object stored in the database.  Can you create a datagrid with images?  Can you query database for items?

Comment: I'm making winform application, I did search on google but doesn't found any useful help Can you tell me first step which control i should choose to do so? can i upload image to show you what I actually want to design?

Comment: A Listview: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enNL863NL863&ei=stGAXZhcgfnBAt23mNAC&q=winforms+listview+tutorial

Comment: Listview does not support images I want to add images and make them grid add text on those images and behind images

Comment: @USMANAMIN but I wouldn't use ListView for that purpose. Check [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview) instead.